# How can I send sparse SQL query results in a DataTable to my grid in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC application there are pivot views that need to be seen in a browser grid.

I'm working with VS 2015 CE, SQL Server, and Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC components.
The project is using ASP.NET 4 and MVC 5.

The grid data source reader is getting data from a pivot view, lab.analysis_across_v, that could have 100+ columns.  For some where criteria the majority of those columns will be mostly null, i.e. sparse.

The grid is setup for virtual scrolling and pages 50 records at a time.

The controller has this method for connecting the query to a DataTable

```
    private DataTable AnalysisPivotView()
    {
        using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from lab.analysis_across_v", db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Mapped);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

[Added] In this example the select * resolves to

```
 select filename,xyz_timestamp,abc_timestamp,import_date,qa_date,containter,test_id,B,C,N,O,Al,Si,P,S,Ti,V,Cr,Mn,Fe,Co,Ni,Cu,Zn,Zr,Nb,Mo,Ag,Sn,Hf,Ta,W,Pb,Bi
 from lab.analysis_across_v
```

The reader sends the data back with this method

```
    public ActionResult Analysis_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        // TODO: Can data transmission be sparse ?

        DataTable apv = AnalysisPivotView();
        DataSourceResult dsr = apv.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        JsonResult jsr = Json(dsr);
        return jsr;
    }
```

The original return was

```
        return Json(AnalysisPivotView().ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

but I broke it up so I could look at the pieces in the debugger. I didn't get very far looking into the pieces actual pre-transmittal because I guess the controller serializes or stringifies things before transmitting.

In the browser the delivered data looks like the following.  Only two rows are shown, but the actual is whatever the paging size is.

The question is: What can be added to the Analysis_Read so that the null items are never sent back to the grid data source read receiver ?

```
    {"Data":
    [{"analysis_id":1672,
    "filename":"166681ON.txt",
    "xyz_timestamp":"\/Date(1484831520000)\/",
    "abc_timestamp":"\/Date(1484857440000)\/",
    "import_date":"\/Date(1487566800000)\/",
    "qa_date":"\/Date(1484802000000)\/",
    "containter":"166681",
    "test_id":"AR 670 LOT 216A",
    "B":null,
    "C":null,
    "N":0.01316,
    "O":0.02474,
    "Al":null,
    "Si":null,
    "P":null,
    "S":null,
    "Ti":null,
    "V":null,
    "Cr":null,
    "Mn":null,
    "Fe":null,
    "Co":null,
    "Ni":null,
    "Cu":null,
    "Zn":null,
    "Zr":null,
    "Nb":null,
    "Mo":null,
    "Ag":null,
    "Sn":null,
    "Hf":null,
    "Ta":null,
    "W":null,
    "Pb":null,
    "Bi":null},
    {"analysis_id":1673,
    "filename":"166681ON.txt",
    "xyz_timestamp":"\/Date(1484855280000)\/",
    "abc_timestamp":"\/Date(1484857440000)\/",
    "import_date":"\/Date(1487566800000)\/",
    "qa_date":"\/Date(1484802000000)\/",
    "containter":"166681",
    "test_id":"166681-1 IN718",
    "B":null,
    "C":null,
    "N":0.00789,
    "O":0.02672,
    "Al":null,
    "Si":null,
    "P":null,
    "S":null,
    "Ti":null,
    "V":null,
    "Cr":null,
    "Mn":null,
    "Fe":null,
    "Co":null,
    "Ni":null,
    "Cu":null,
    "Zn":null,
    "Zr":null,
    "Nb":null,
    "Mo":null,
    "Ag":null,
    "Sn":null,
    "Hf":null,
    "Ta":null,
    "W":null,
    "Pb":null,
    "Bi":null},
    ],
    "Total":2,
    "AggregateResults":null,
    "Errors":null}
```

Comment: Add a Where clause to your Select statement so that it does not pull in Null values.  Then your source is filtered before it even gets back that far.

Comment: The select is grabbing many columns.  There are no columns where all the values are NULL.  There are many rows where most of the columns are NULL.  So, unfortunately I can not reduce the row count of the select.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to sort out everything to that degree.  If there is a chance there might be a value in any of the columns, you would have to send that data (be it null or not) for display.  You could analyze the data after retrieving it and determine where there are consistent nulls in columns (this case, Al has nulls in both records) and then remove those columns.